# How do I get Python to talk to the portmidi c library on Windows 11/64

Tags: python, windows, cython, ctypes, pyportmidi

I'm trying to get [portmidi](https://github.com/PortMidi/portmidi) working with Python on Windows 11/64.  I'm able to compile the dll/lib in MSVS without errors, without specifying any changes or options.  I'm new to this, so I don't know how to tell the system about the libraries, do I have to put them on some path or something?  For now I'm just telling Python their location in the build directory directly.

I'd like to get two approaches working in order to compare them.

First way: [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).  I stumbled across [portmidizero](https://pypi.org/project/portmidizero/#files), which looks old and dead, but basically correct.  I have to [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) it and fix a few tiny errors, but then it almost works.  Running `testportmidizero.py`, I can `Initialize()`, list the devices and get sensible names, open an `Output`, and run the `Time()` function, all without errors.  But then when I try to `Pm_write()`, I get `OSError: Access Violation`.  I am running as administrator.  Googling, my best guess is that there's a problem either with calling conventions or pointer sizes.  But I don't see any mention of `cdecl` or `stdcall` anywhere, so I think everything has defaulted to `cdecl`, but I don't know how to verify.  And I don't see any problem with how the pointer types/sizes are written, but I barely know what I'm doing.  What should I do to figure out what's wrong?

Second way: [Cython](https://cython.org/).  As far as I understand this approach will give the best performance.  [pyportmidi](https://github.com/PortMidi/pm_python) used to work well on mac several years ago, but is now out of date.  I tried to get `pip install` working:

- Remove the `description` related stuff from `setup.py` because the expected `readme` is missing.  Same for all testing related stuff.
- I couldn't figure out how to add a path to the portmidi header files, the compiler couldn't find them when I added the path to `include_dirs`, even though it looked correct in the compiler directive output.  I just manually copied the `.h`'s into the `pyportmidi` directory for now.
- But then I got all the following errors I have no idea how to solve:

```
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(399): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'long', possible loss of data
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(419): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'long', possible loss of data
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(441): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'long', possible loss of data
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(2093): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int32_t', possible loss of data
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(2625): warning C4113: 'PtTimestamp (__cdecl *)(void)' differs in parameter lists from 'PmTimeProcPtr'
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(3455): error C2105: '++' needs l-value
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(3458): error C2105: '--' needs l-value
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(3634): error C2105: '++' needs l-value
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(3637): error C2105: '--' needs l-value
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(4554): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE': deprecated in 3.3
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(4568): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE': deprecated in 3.3
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(5523): warning C4047: 'function': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(5523): warning C4024: 'PyCode_New': different types for formal and actual parameter 14
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(5525): warning C4047: 'function': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'PyObject *'
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(5524): warning C4024: 'PyCode_New': different types for formal and actual parameter 15
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(5507): error C2198: 'PyCode_New': too few arguments for call
      pyportmidi\_pyportmidi.c(5534): error C2037: left of 'f_lineno' specifies undefined struct/union '_frame'
```

I assume these need to be fixed by editing the `.pyx` with knowledge of how the c library has been updated.  But I don't know Cython/pyrex, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: pyportmidi has to old generated c-files. You need to regenerate them. I didn't look into the setup.py so not sure, how it should be done in this case. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65696724/5769463 for a similar issue.

Comment: Doesn't https://pypi.org/project/pyo help?

Comment: @ead you were right!  how did you discern that?  i deleted the old one and pip install automatically made a new one.  i'll update with some minor fixes i had to do, but this got it working, thanks!

Comment: @CristiFati, pyo seems to have their own c wrapper around portmidi?  it doesn't look like it's designed to be easily used on its own https://github.com/belangeo/pyo/blob/master/src/engine/md_portmidi.c and i can't discern their intent or how they call into their c lib from python?  i specifically want plain portmidi cuz i have old projects written against it.